# Pausing a Linux thread for a certain amount of time

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer

Suppose I have two threads running on Linux in a single process and I want to pause one thread for .5s,how would I do this without blocking the other thread?

Comment: Check the man reference for [pthread_cond_timedwait(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_timedwait), which does exactly what you're wanting to do. You pass the absolute time of when the thread should execute (essentially current_time + delay), getting the current time with [clock_gettime(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59117450/7554558) for a starting point.

Comment: @OwenSullivan Why to involve conditional variables and clock instead of just `nanosleep()`?

Comment: @dimich Primarily thread safety. `nanosleep()` is not guaranteed to be thread safe, whereas `pthread_cond_timedwait()` in combination with a mutex and condition variable is.

Comment: @OwenSullivan Where does it say that `nanosleep()` is not thread safe? `nanosleep()` uses `clock_nanosleep()` system call, the same as C++ `std::thread::sleep_for()`uses.

Comment: @dimich What I should have said is that `nanosleep()` may not be thread safe in certain applications, such as when multiple threads are being paused using `nanosleep()`, if shared resources are not being protected appropriately, if signal handlers are being used, etc. That being said, doing some more digging into this topic has revealed that using one function over another is highly dependent on use case and implementation, so at this point I think we've laid out two good options for OP.